# paperclip and rails 3 - NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

So I just installed paperclip and am trying to get it working in my brand new Rails app.

But this is the error I keep getting, when I go to localhost/upload/new:

```
NoMethodError in Upload#new
undefined method `uploads_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000102d1b8e0>:0x00000102cf24e0>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <h1>Upload Images</h1>
2: 
3: <%= form_for @upload, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
4:  <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
5:  <div>
6:      <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
```

I solved another error with Paperclip, by including the following line in my config/application.rb file:

```
Paperclip::Railtie.insert
```

The way my app is structured is that I have created a model called 'uploads', because the app will be managing various file types - uploaded by the users. Paperclip is managing the images.

The Upload controller looks like this:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
    @title = "Upload"
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

end
```

So my Upload model looks like this:

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :description, :type

    has_attached_file :image
end
```

This is how my new.html.erb file looks:

```
<h1>Upload Images</h1>

<%= form_for @upload, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= render 'fields', :f => f %>
    <div>
        <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The partial looks like this:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :type %>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
</div>
```

P.S. I am just learning Rails, so if there are rookie/noob mistakes, please don't crucify me :|

Thanks.

Edit: Here is the output for rakes route for the app, as Zabba asked:

```
comment_index GET /comment/index(.:format)   {:controller=>"comment", :action=>"index"}
   comment_show GET /comment/show(.:format)    {:controller=>"comment", :action=>"show"}
    comment_new GET /comment/new(.:format)     {:controller=>"comment", :action=>"new"}
   comment_edit GET /comment/edit(.:format)    {:controller=>"comment", :action=>"edit"}
 comment_delete GET /comment/delete(.:format)  {:controller=>"comment", :action=>"delete"}
   upload_index GET /upload/index(.:format)    {:controller=>"upload", :action=>"index"}
    upload_show GET /upload/show(.:format)     {:controller=>"upload", :action=>"show"}
     upload_new GET /upload/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"upload", :action=>"new"}
    upload_edit GET /upload/edit(.:format)     {:controller=>"upload", :action=>"edit"}
  upload_delete GET /upload/delete(.:format)   {:controller=>"upload", :action=>"delete"}
  project_index GET /project/index(.:format)   {:controller=>"project", :action=>"index"}
   project_show GET /project/show(.:format)    {:controller=>"project", :action=>"show"}
    project_new GET /project/new(.:format)     {:controller=>"project", :action=>"new"}
   project_edit GET /project/edit(.:format)    {:controller=>"project", :action=>"edit"}
 project_delete GET /project/delete(.:format)  {:controller=>"project", :action=>"delete"}
   client_index GET /client/index(.:format)    {:controller=>"client", :action=>"index"}
    client_show GET /client/show(.:format)     {:controller=>"client", :action=>"show"}
     client_new GET /client/new(.:format)      {:controller=>"client", :action=>"new"}
    client_edit GET /client/edit(.:format)     {:controller=>"client", :action=>"edit"}
  client_delete GET /client/delete(.:format)   {:controller=>"client", :action=>"delete"}
 designer_index GET /designer/index(.:format)  {:controller=>"designer", :action=>"index"}
  designer_show GET /designer/show(.:format)   {:controller=>"designer", :action=>"show"}
   designer_new GET /designer/new(.:format)    {:controller=>"designer", :action=>"new"}
  designer_edit GET /designer/edit(.:format)   {:controller=>"designer", :action=>"edit"}
designer_delete GET /designer/delete(.:format) {:controller=>"designer", :action=>"delete"}
           root     /(.:format)                {:controller=>"project", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: What is the output of the `rake routes` command for your app? Is there a path called `uploads_path` in that list?

Comment: @Zabba, updated the post with the output.

Comment: `uploads_path` isn't in the list of routes you posted. You need to have that. So, whats the info in your `routes.rb` file? Is there something like `map.resources :uploads` in there?

Comment: Nope. Just a lot of `'get "designer/delete"'` for all the REST resources and controllers and models listed above. I will try map.resources: uploads and see what happens.

Comment: Also take a look at the **excellent** *RailsCasts by Ryan Bates*. The ones relevant to routing : http://railscasts.com/tags/14

Comment: When I specified `resources :uploads` that worked. :) Thanks man. Btw, you should add that as an answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your maps file, add:

For Rails 2.x:

```
map.resources :uploads
```

For Rails 3.x:

```
resources :uploads
```

This will add all the routes for the 7 RESTful actions and `users_path` will then work.

Comment: although, the syntax isn't 100% accurate. I don't think `map.resources` works in rails 3. It is just `resources :uploads` in my case.

Comment: correct. Updated the answer. I missed the fact you were on Rails 3.